# Picker.js get date in Javacript

Tags: javascript, date, pick

Trying to create a picker in Javascript where I can get the date out of (and the time, eventually). I have made it in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ariley/ej37qv5w/18/

Here's the JS part of the code:

```
   const picker = new Picker(document.querySelector('.js-inline-picker'), {
  controls: true,
  inline: true,
increment: {
    year: 1,
    month: 1,
    day: 1,
    hour: 1,
    minute: 15,
  },
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
            date: new Date(), // default to today's date
            text: {
                title: 'Pick a date',
            },
});



        // Listen for when a date is selected
        picker.getDate('pick', function(date) {
            // Date is picked. Let's store it!
            const selectedDate = date.format('YYYY/MM/DD');
            console.log('Selected Date:', selectedDate); // Or do whatever you wish with it
            
            // Example: Storing in localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('selectedDate', selectedDate);
        });
```

I'm unable to get the date, but there are no errors. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!